# Window Phone Hybrid Apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing window phone apps in Phone-gap

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

is not working on window phone,
please let me know where am i wrong with this stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure about phone-gap (and the 'translation' it does to make a windows-phone application), but as far as I know, windows-phone 8 does not natively supports break-word. Windows-Phone 8.1 has `TextWrapping="{Wrap, NoWrap, WrapWholeWords}"` available for some controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 word-break:break-all
```

It will support in window phone Hybrid Apps,
But it may create unwanted Break.